# What is $\int|x^n|dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to solve $$\int|x^n| \, dx$$ **if n is an odd positive integer**.

I think it should be $\dfrac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}+c$, but this is wrong. I am new to integration so I don’t know what to do when there is modulus function.

The answer given at back of book is $\dfrac{|x^n|x}{n+1} +c$.

If $x$ is real or complex isn’t mentioned.

Comment: Where does $x$ live?  There are different ways of approaching an answer to your question, depending on whether $x$ is real, complex, a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, etc.

Comment: On what domain are you integrating ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Edited question @XanderHenderson

Comment: Again, is $x$ a real number?

Comment: @Xander I dont think that being new to integration the OP know something more complicate than real numbers.

Comment: @Masacroso Indeed, but he also used the word "modulus," which I have never seen outside of complex analysis.  The Google informs me that it can be used synonymously with the absolute value, but that is a new one on me (perhaps it is an American vs British English thing?  or a regional thing? or I've just led a sheltered life? *shrugs*).

Comment: @Typhon: certainly not.

Comment: @Typhon: what's $\int |z|^n dz$ ?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: you can rewrite the indefinite integral as

$$\int |x^n|\mathrm dx=\int |x|^n\mathrm dx=\int(\operatorname{sign}(x))^nx^n\mathrm dx=\int\operatorname{sign}(x^n)x^n\mathrm dx,\quad n\in\Bbb N_{>0}\tag1$$

where

$$\operatorname{sign}(x):=\begin{cases}1,&x> 0\\-1,&x<0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}\tag2$$

and

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\operatorname{sign}(x^n)=0,\quad\text{for } n\in\Bbb N_{>0}\,\text{ and whenever } x\neq 0\tag3$$

Then applying integration by parts in $(1)$ we finally get

$$\int |x|^n\mathrm dx=\operatorname{sign}(x^n)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\tag4$$

what is *almost* an indefinite integral in the general accepted convention, that is, the RHS is almost an antiderivative of the integrand because

$$\left[\operatorname{sign}(x^n)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\right]'=|x|^n,\quad\text{whenever }x\neq 0\tag5$$

If $n>1$ is odd then we have that $\operatorname{sign}(x^n)x^{n+1}=x|x^n|$. Also note that I used the identity $|x^n|=|x|^n$, for $n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$. Thus for odd $n>1$ the result on $(4)$ becomes an indefinite integral in the general convention.

Comment: I have added the answer in my question.

Comment: It seems the OP has just changed the game from $|x|^n$ to $\left| x^n \right|$…

Comment: @Chase its fine, they are equivalent, at least for $n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: @Masacroso 

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x$ is a real number and $n$ is odd, we have $$
|x|^n = \begin{cases}
x^n & \text{if}\ x\geq 0, \\
-x^n & \text{if}\ x<0.
\end{cases}$$
Use this to remove the modulus. That is, the antiderivative will be different depending on whether $x$ is positive or negative. For example, the antiderivative of $|x|$ is
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}x^2+C & \text{if}\ x>0, \\
-\frac{1}{2}x^2+C & \text{if}\ x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
What about at $x=0$?

Comment: I have edited question.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

$|x^n|$ is an even function so that its antiderivative must be odd (to a constant), i.e. have the sign of $x$. This explains

$$\frac{|x^n|x}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Stupid downvote.